# SQLcl - Connect using keystore

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

Does anyone know how to pass keystore to the SQLcl command line ?

~/sqlcl/bin/sql HOST:PORT -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=Path to file

Comment: According to the documentation, you set the options with SET JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-D... before launching sqlcl. (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/sql-developer-command-line/20.3/sqcug/oracle-sqlcl-users-guide.pdf)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.